# Backbone count number of models in a collection that have attributes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to get the number of models that appear in a collection where the attribute value appears in an array, for example I have an array,

`var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

I wanting to get the number of models from a collection that have an attribute called status that is equal to one those values in the array is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter out all the models which has a status contained in the array, and then take the length of this resulting array:

```
var numOfModels = collection.filter(function(model) { 
  return array.indexOf(model.get('status')) !== -1;
}).length;
```

Answer (score 3):

Underscore has a method called [where](http://underscorejs.org/#where) which you could do to get a list of models in the collection with an attribute status. Once you get the list it's just a matter of doing list.length

```
var status_len = collection.where({status: true}).length
```

you could also use [_.filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) if you needed to do some more in-depth checks.